# A design pattern for two different "strategies", that do not implement the same interface

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, websocket, socket.io

I've built some program with ReactJS and SocketIO, that serves as a fully customizable tool for communicating with a socketIO server.

You can register events to listen to, send messages of any type, pass configuration object to the connection, etc.

Now i've decided to add support for native websockets. The problem is, that native web sockets are simpler, and do not implement the same functionality that SocketIO does.

For instance, i have this method in my React container(where all my main logic is concentrated, no Redux):

```
registerEventToSocket = (instanceId, socket, eventName) => {
      socket.off(eventName);

      socket.on(eventName, (...args) => {           
        const lastArg = args[args.length - 1];
        const isFunction = this.isFunction(lastArg);

        if (isFunction) {
          lastArg();//If a callback was supplied from the server, it is invoked.
          var index = args.indexOf(lastArg);
          if (index > -1) {
            args.splice(index, 1);
          }

        }

        this.addMessageToState(instanceId, eventName, args, false)
      })
    }
```

This method is called when the user "adds an event" to listen to. In the case of native websockets, there is only one event to listen to, which is "onmessage" event, so this whole functionality is irrelevant.

The app does few more things that would be useless with native sockets, like an option to "listen to all incoming events".

I'm trying to think of some good design pattern, which i could use to create some polymorphism here, to deal both with the SocketIO case, and the native one.

I'm familair with "strategy pattern", which i used a lot, **but in my case both "strategies" would implement two different interfaces**, which would violate SOLID principles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an organic evolution of a typical program. I think your main issue now is deciding which features your baseline driver will support. As it stands, the client is too coupled to the implementation (SocketIO). You'll need to define an interface for all WebSocket drivers and adapt implementations to it.

Strategy pattern doesn't apply here, that's a behavioral pattern. This is a structural issue. You can use an Adapter or Bridge based on your requirements.

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you! But how would i approach the methods that are relevant ONLY for SocketIO, like the listenToAllEvents that i've mentioned? The NativeSocket can't and shouldn't implement such a method. What would the good way for dealing with a situation where two modules implement an interface that is only PARTIALLY identical?

Comment: When an implementation doesn't support a method, it shouldn't handle the request (method call). This is common. Returning nothing or an empty array or null, etc., are all valid no-ops.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the cost of supporting multiple implementations: you have to support least-common-denominator style, losing particular features of some implementations unless you decide it is important enough to have, so you include it in your base client and most implementations will simply no-op it.

Comment: I was thinking about this "do nothing" option you mentioned, and i also saw such an implementation in Head first design patterns i think. My question is: Doesn't such an approach violate the Liskow substitution principle? I mean, we are just using some "hack" to evade the problem of unused methods.

Comment: No, it actually aheres to the Liskov Substitution Principle by allowing implementations to be swapped without issue. No-op overrides are very common.

Comment: Clients need not worry whether an implementation supports a particular feature or not. It can simply assume it does without consequence.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your explanations.